# Any ideas to make this dataset stationary?

Tags: arima, stationarity

I'm trying to make this graph (of the monthly withdrawal rate of natural gas in the US) stationary, though I can't seem to do so.

[image: this graph]

I've tried differencing of multiple orders, logging then differencing, and cubed rooting then differing.  I plan to forecast this data with ARIMA (maybe SARIMA), so I need a way to recover the original value.

Any ideas on how I could achieve stationarity?

Thanks!

Comment: And, I presume, you've tried a linear trend, possibly together with those other things?

Comment: @John Madden Yes, but still no cigar.  I'm thinking of just fitting a smooth curve of high degree and trying to difference that.

Comment: It probably goes wrong because you have a behaviour with some change points. You might try fitting some spline with the noise as an ARIMA process. Then for the extrapolation, you need to consider the possibility that the spline has a probability to not extrapolate well